# How can I stop opencv from making calls to qDebug?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I've just started using OpenCv 3.1 and have encountered the following annoying behavior. Whenever I make an initial call to `imshow` (actually `cv2.imshow`, since I'm using the Python interface), I get this output to my screen:

```
init done
opengl support available
```

It seems to be due to the following method in window_QT.cpp:

```
static int icvInitSystem(int* c, char** v)
{
    //"For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely one QApplication object"
    if (!QApplication::instance())
    {
        new QApplication(*c, v);
        setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");

        qDebug() << "init done";

#ifdef HAVE_QT_OPENGL
        qDebug() << "opengl support available";
#endif
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All I can think of to do is to comment out the qDebug calls and recompile OpenCV. Is there any less drastic solution that would either automatically redirect qDebug's output to stderr, or just turnoff debug information unless I actively want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qDebug` is a preprocessor-controlled, but it has its own special macro, `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT`. If you add that to your Release build defines, it will be removed.